# How to extend sidebar by creating an empty container to the end of context

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[image: convert 1 -> 2]

I already tried some process found on internet. Some of them, i couldn't understand and some of them were creating a column on a single container. What i actually looking is to convert as like 'image 1' to 'image 2' shown in image above.

**style.css**

```
#container {
float: left;
margin: 0 -240px 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

#content {
margin: 0 280px 0 20px;
 }

#primary,
#secondary {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
width: 220px;
}

#secondary {
clear: right;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

**functions.php**

```
function tnc_widgets_init() {register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => __( 'Fourth Widget Area', 'twentyten' ),
                'id' => 'fourth-widget-area',
                'description' => __( 'An optional secondary widget area, ', 'twentyten' ),

                'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</li>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) 
                );
        }
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'tnc_widgets_init' );
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<div id="" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <ul class="xoxo">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'fourth-widget-area' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What i want is to display new widget areas, and make it display even if there is no content to display and extend it to the bottom (to the same height of column).
Thanks.

Comment: use flexbox , it is the easiest way to have 2 containers have the same height .

Comment: could you explain the procedure?

Comment: I will use a simple example and then you can relate it to your id's and containers... container A has two child elements content B and Sidebar C.....containerA {
  display: flex;
}

.contentB {
  flex: 3 1 auto;
}
.sideBarC {
  flex: 1 1 225px;
}

Comment: This is the basic structure and you can add more styles to this..Learn Flexbox and it will help you a lot..it is easy and will save a lot of time and headache..I cannot help you explain everything here but flex property which you see for contentB says that when the screen size grows it will grow 3 times more than sideBarC and both content and SideBar will shrink by 1 when size decreases and sidebarC will start with 225px but contentB will take whatever remaining is available..height by default will be same for both content and sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

there is no id set in sidebar.php file .... also you don't need to clear any div alone while you are clearing both with your footer section ....hope that makes sense

Comment: am using id= "secondary" but still that does not work

Comment: kindly give me your full html code so that I can provide you styling accordingly .... there is very simple rule to follow, just float your divs left with their respective width, and then clear both to footer ... that will give you your desired result ... let suppose your styling is : #primary{width: 66%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;} #secondary{width: 32%; float: left;} #footer{ clear: both;} ... if there is your primary id div, secondary id div and footer id div ... apply these styles you will get your desired layout ... hope that works for you by now ...